# Game Center Air Native Extension. Connection error

Tags: macos, air, game-center, air-native-extension

Making a Game Center ANE for OS X.
When my app was unsigned, (and with enabled workaround, described here https://devforums.apple.com/message/736545), it works fine.
But when I sign my app for distribution, and disable workaround, it raise errors, when I try to authorize local player

`Could not get services from gamed. Please file a radar including GameKit logs, and any gamed crash logs. ERROR Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (The connection to service named com.apple.gamed.osx was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x325c90 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.gamed.osx was invalidated.}`

`Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server." UserInfo=0x21ce90 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.}`

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Here is script, which I use to sign my app:

```
App=MyApp.app
Cert=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: ...

rm "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/WebKit.dylib
rm "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/adobecp.vch
rm -rf "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/adobecp.plugin
rm -rf "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/AdobeCP15.plugin
rm "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Adobe\ AIR.vch

chmod -R 777 "$App"/

codesign -f -v -s "$Cert" "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Flash\ Player.plugin/
codesign -f -v -s "$Cert" "$App"/Contents/Frameworks/Adobe\ AIR.framework/

codesign -f -v -s "$Cert" "$App"/Contents/Resources/META-INF/AIR/extensions/my.awesome.gc/META-INF/ANE/MacOS-x86/GC.framework/GC 

codesign -f -s "$Cert" --entitlements MyApp.entitlements "$App"
```

UPD

The problem occurs only if I sign with the --entitlements MyApp.entitlements.

Here is MyApp.entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please, tell me, what am i doing wrong?